# Check if keydown event for umlaute

Tags: javascript, char, dom-events, keycode

I want to check via `eventListener` if the pressed key is an umlaut (<kbd>ä</kbd>, <kbd>ö</kbd>, <kbd>ü</kbd>). The problem is that the `charCode`/`keyCode` is always 0 and if I am not mistaken the value is also used for some control keys.

I tried tried to parse the `e.which` of the `keyDown` to something I can work with, but until now nothing seems to work. It would be nice if I could do something like `'ä'.atCharCode()`.

Any help? :)
Or is it fine and safe to check for the `0`?

Comment: **Update:** Actually this problem is only with Firefox. In Chrome the charCode of the umlaut is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. In Chrome everthing is fine and umlaute are getting the correct charCode. In Firefox on the other hand it seems like there is no real support for umlaute and their charCode is always 0. The FF I tested in was 17.0.1

So if you want to solve this problem, you have to don't allow events with a `e.keyCode`/`e.which` of `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox uses for these particular characters the key-code 0. For all other browser it is 186, 192 and 222.

For example if you want to check if alphabetical keys + umlauts are pressed I use the following code:

```
$('.myInputBox').keydown(function(e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [0, 186, 192, 222]) != -1 || (e.keyCode > 64 && e.keyCode < 91)) {  
        alert('valid key!');
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('no valid key!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function disablekeys(e) {
            var e = event || evt;
            var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
            if (charCode = 8) {
                //your code here
            }
        }
</script>
```

Find char code from following link
http://www.expandinghead.net/keycode.html

Comment: I know who to capture them. But I was confused b/c in FF the code is euqal to zero.